# I found this PowerShell process, and I think it might be malicious

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, malware

This process starts on my computer every time I log in:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "powershell -Command "& { [Console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.UTF8Encoding]::UTF8; $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; $applications = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[String]; 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs','C:\Users\Z\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu','C:\Users\Z\Desktop' | %{ Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -include *.lnk, *.appref-ms, *.url, *.exe -Recurse -File | % { $applications.Add($_.FullName) } }; $result = (@{ errors = @($error | ForEach-Object { $_.Exception.Message }); applications = $applications } | ConvertTo-Json); Write-Host $result; }""
```

I don't know enough Powershell to view exactly what it does.
Thanks

Comment: Does nothing malicious really. Just gets all the users shortcut names and writes a json output to a console not shown. Not sure what it would be trying to accomplish

Comment: The script essentially pulls a list of all the applications and links from your Start Menu and desktop. Not "necessarily" malicious, but it depends on the context. E.g. could be an inventory script?

Comment: Thanks to both! But is strange, no? A random cmd execution...

Comment: I just realized that I have ueli installed, and that from time to time it refreshes the indeces ... it could be, right?